# Multiple anchor link menus active anchor class

Tags: jquery, css, menu, anchor

I have multiple menus full of anchor links on a one-page website that looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="active" onclick="closeNav();">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" onclick="closeNav();">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" onclick="closeNav();">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news" onclick="closeNav();">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

I found some code that'll allow me to add an active class to the current anchor link, but the code doesn't highlight all the instances.

For example, I have a menu at the top and bottom of the site that have different ID's, but when I click the "About" anchor, only the "About" anchor in the menu that I click on get's the active class - instead of both "About" anchor links that are on the page.

The jQuery I am using looks like:

```
$("#top-nav li, #foot-nav li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#top-nav,     
    #foot-nav').find('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
});
```

Is there any way to change the function so that when `#about` or any other anchor is clicked, the "About" link in both menus gets an active class?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general 'this' in your case is only one item and it's the item that you just clicked. Yes you added event listener to both navs items, but you always click only one per time. To find all same items you need to search in the callback for all items with the same anchor in different navs and then add/remove 'active' class. Probably you can improve this code and mb reduce it.

See working code here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgOyWj.

```
html:
<ul id="top-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" >About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" >Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news" >News</a></li>
</ul>

  <ul id="foot-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" >About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
</ul>


css: 
.active a { color: green; }


js:
const navsStr = '#foot-nav li, #top-nav li';

$(navsStr).on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  let items = $(navsStr).find('a[href$="' + href + '"]');
  $(items).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');  
});
```